# Cannot parse a list of guns and ammo types to array and display results

Tags: ruby, file, parsing

I am learning Ruby and practicing parsing a list of guns from a video game - I followed a instructional and did exactly how they parsed a list of names/ages but I cannot get this code to run...

I've tried creating a Guns.new(name, ammo) before the parse which did not work..

```
# FILE IN FORMAT "gun, ammo" IS IN "gunsammo.txt"
def load_guns(filename)
  guns = []
# load gun names and ammo types from file "gunsammo.txt"
  file = File.open(filename, "r+").read
  file.lines do |line|
    gun_type = line.split(", ")
    name = gun_type.first #[0]
    ammo = gun_type.last.to_s #[1]
    gun = Guns.new(name, ammo)
    guns << gun
    # puts "imported #{gun.display}"
  end
  # RETURN GUNS FROM TEXT gunsammo.txt
  guns
end

eft_guns = load_guns("gunsammo.txt")
eft_guns.each {|gun| p guns}
```

I expected to get an output of the following list in array format:

```
[
ADAR 2-15, 5.56x45mm NATO
AK-101, 5.56x45mm NATO
AK-102, 5.56x45mm NATO
AK-103, 7.62x39mm
AK-104, 7.62x39mm
AK-105, 5.45x39mm
AK-74, 5.45x39mm
AK-74M, 5.45x39mm
AK-74N, 5.45x39mm
]
```

Instead I get these errors:

```
enter code here

/RUBY/class_ammo.rb:11:in `block in load_guns': uninitialized constant Guns (NameError)
    from C:/Users/**/Documents/CODING/RUBY/class_ammo.rb:7:in `lines'
    from C:/Users/**/Documents/CODING/RUBY/class_ammo.rb:7:in `load_guns'
    from C:/Users/**/Documents/CODING/RUBY/class_ammo.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you defined a `Guns` class?

Comment: I just tried that, didnt work.

Comment: `File.open(filename, "r+").read` opens the file for reading and then reads it, but you have not later closed it (and can't because you don't have the file handle `f = File.open(filename)`. (`"r"` is not needed as it is the default; I'm not familiar with `"r+"`.) Better: `File.read(filename)`, which closes the file after it is read. All the elements of `gun_type` are strings, so `.to_s` in `gun_type.last.to_s` is redundant. You need to edit show the class `Gun`, even if it's somewhat simplified. The error message makes it clear that Ruby hasn't seen it, which is the heart of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby doesn't know what Guns is. You need to define a Guns class. Actually, I'd name it Gun, as a class name usually should be singular.

```
class Gun
    attr_reader :name
    attr_reader :ammo

    def initialize ( name, ammo )
        @name = name
        @ammo = ammo
    end
end
```

Also your input file is never closed. To read a file line by line, you can use this handy method:

```
File.readlines(filename).each do |line|
    # Do something with line
end
```

Using this method, the file is automatically closed at the end.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I know it is probably obvious to everyone, but I was missing that! I added the class and define it but now when I run the code I do not get any output... Even when I put "puts guns" after the .readlines

Comment: @Rainbird Please always update the question to reflect your current code. Updating doesn't mean to edit what you've written so far but attach an update to what you've written at then end to reflect progress, then people can comment on your changes. And it would be useful to provide a small excerpt of the text file you are trying to parse, 3 lines are enough.